# Python outputting a dictionary into excel file

Tags: python, excel, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in a txt format - this is part of the file (it contains 6000 keys:values:

```
{'YAL008W': 25, 'YBR255W': 50, 'YGR164W': 37, 'YGR131W': 40, 'YNL003C': 11, 'YBR135W': 2, 'YBR160W': 6, 'YJL082W': 79, 'YJL142C': 4, 'YPL191C': 38, 'YGL215W': 31, 'YKL074C': 33, 'YJL077C': 67, 'YKL096W-A': 22, 'YIL124W': 60, 'YLR364C-A': 2, 'YPL039W': 58, 'YNL170W': 16, 'YGL141W': 62, 'YJL179W': 15, 'YDR316W-A': 13, 'YDR316W-B': 139, 'YKL083W': 25, 'YOR009W': 25, 'YKL029C': 395, 'YPL166W': 31, 'YKL052C': 20, 'YOL034W': 29, 'YBL008W': 42}
```

I would like to output this dictionary into Excel. Excel takes up tab-delimited file format. Another way I can go about it is to create two lists and get rid of single quote around 'key'. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So what is the expected output, one row for each key-value pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to produce Excel-acceptable output. The default dialect is Excel compatible using commas, but you can also switch to a tab-delimited dialect.

Outputing the dictionary as key-value pairs:

```
import csv

with open(outputfilename, 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    # to get tabs use csv.writer(outfile, dialect='excel-tab')
    writer.writerows(your_dictionary.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the really nice library:  xlsxwriter - http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/index.html and just create the Excel very neatly.

--

You could also use pandas and its ExcelWriter function. The basic idea is:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, ExcelWriter

myDF = DataFrame(myDictionary)
writer = ExcelWriter(someFileName)
myDF.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```